# 2loops in single workbook hence want to run loops based on sheets <> only

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to run this code correctly on all the sheets without any issues but i am not able to run the code on particular sheets only.

I tried using
`if w.Name <> array("Summary", "-NonkeyRitemsgreaterthan180","Bus Jus R with Non-Jus Sub Type", "Close date" like this i have 20 sheets on which i dont want to run this code but its not working.It would be great help if any one can guide or help me on this as i am running another loop for these sheets.

Correct code:

```
Dim w
Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
Dim cK As Long, cN As Long, cH As Long, cL As Long, cM As Long, cB As Long, cC As Long, LastR As Long
Dim sh, sM, sL, sB
Dim cY As Long, cT As Long, cR As Long
Dim sT, sR


Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Summary"
With Sheets("Summary")
    .Range("C3") = "Checks Performed"
    .Range("D3") = "No. Of Issues Found"
    .Range("E3") = "Key"
    .Range("F3") = "Non-Key"
    .Range("G3") = "High"
    .Range("H3") = "Medium"
    .Range("I3") = "Low"
    .Range("J3") = "Blanks"
    .Range("K3") = "High"
    .Range("L3") = "Medium"
    .Range("M3") = "Low"
    .Range("N3") = "Blanks"

    .Range("E2") = "Key /Non-Key "
    .Range("G2") = "Count"
    .Range("K2") = "Sum"
    .Range("E2:F2").Merge
    .Range("G2:J2").Merge
    .Range("K2:N2").Merge
End With

i = 4
For Each w In Worksheets
If w.Name <> "Summary" Then
    With w
        LastR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'added lineššššššššššššššššššššššššššš
        cK = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B:B"), "Key")
        cN = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B:B"), "Non-Key")
        cH = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("L:L"), "High")
        cM = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("L:L"), "Medium")
        cL = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("L:L"), "Low")
        'cB = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("L:L"), " ")
        cB = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Range("L2"), .Cells(LastR, 12)), "") 'changed line
        sh = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("L:L"), "High", .Range("N:N"))
        sM = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("L:L"), "Medium", .Range("N:N"))
        sL = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("L:L"), "Low", .Range("N:N"))
        sB = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("L:L"), "", .Range("N:N"))
        cC = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A2:A100000"))
    End With
    With Sheets("Summary")
        .Cells(i, 3).Value = w.Name
        .Cells(i, 4).Value = cC
        .Cells(i, 5).Value = cK
        .Cells(i, 6).Value = cN
        .Cells(i, 7).Value = cH
        .Cells(i, 8).Value = cM
        .Cells(i, 9).Value = cL
        .Cells(i, 10).Value = cB
        .Cells(i, 11).Value = sh
        .Cells(i, 12).Value = sM
        .Cells(i, 13).Value = sL
        .Cells(i, 14).Value = sL
        i = i + 1
    End With
End If
```

Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Select Case`

```
For each w in Worksheets
    Select Case w.Name
        Case Is = "Summary", "-NonkeyRitemsgreaterthan180","Bus Jus R with Non-Jus Sub Type", "Close date" '... add more as needed
        Case Else
            '... execute code
    End Select
Next
```

Another, perhaps more manageable, option is to load all your sheet names into a [Named Range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) in your spreadsheet and do a test against the named range.

```
For each w in Worksheets
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("SkipSheets").Find(What:=w.Name, lookat:=xlWhole) is Nothing Then 
       'execute code ...
    End If
Next
```

Assumed named range of `SkipSheets` located in `Sheet1`

Comment: Thank you Scott :) will be trying this and have a great weekend!!

Comment: Thank you Scott Holtzman it worked out i tried the first one it worked out even any of the sheets is not available in the current file as i tried with exhausting list of sheets which shouldn't be considered..

Comment: great @suresh7860 - please mark as answered, if it is indeed so!